# Unity Android Build Support Stuck At Validating

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, frameworks, game-development

so im using unity 2022.3.15f1 and unity hub 3.7.0 to download android build support but it just stops at validating and doesn't end the process even after the 3rd shot. I've seen some people talking ab the download location whatsoever but didn't understand what setting them the same mean. advanced thanks[image]

I tried changing it some times but nothing happened; also, idk if im supposed to redownload everything again.

Comment: you need to look in the logs see what it is doing

Comment: could you please explain more. if you want any other details tell me